# How to create an IHostBuilder extension?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to access the `appsettings.json` at an early stage, so I created an extension method for `IHostBuilder`:

```
public static class MyClass1 
{
    public static bool property1
    public static string property2;

    public static IHostBuilder UseMyService(this IHostBuilder builder, Action<HostBuilderContext> context)
    {
        //Here what?

        return builder;
    }

    public static MyServiceClass MyService => new MyServiceClass(property1, property2);
}
```

And in `Program.cs` I did:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
        {
            var builder = config.Build();
            var env = context.HostingEnvironment;

            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        })
        .UseMyService((context) => 
        {
            //Here what?        
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

I need to set the properties `property1` and `property2` from the configuration ( I know how to do that).

But do I need to set them in `UseMyService` extension method (I only have an Action there) or in `CreateHostBuilder`?

Comment: Look at the `Configuration` property of the `HostBuilderContext`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: Yes I know there's the `Configuration` property. But where exactly do I set the properties?

Comment: What do you mean with "set the properties"?

Comment: If you need to _set_ configuration changes, then you need to do that in `ConfigureAppConfiguration()` using the configuration builder (e.g. by using `AdInMemoryCollection`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#memory-configuration-provider

Comment: You need to give more details, or we cannot give you a complete answer. Why are the properties static? Why is the class static? What are the properties? Note the whole `ConfigureAppConfiguration` part is not needed: `CreateDefaultBuilder` already does all those things for you (and more).

Comment: "at an early stage" how early? which stage? Why are you trying to do this against `IHostBuilder` rather than in `Startup.ConfigureServices` or by using DI with some `IOptions<T>` or perhaps needing some `IConfigureOptions<T>`?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I need to set some properties that will be used by Serilog. The only way to do it is before Serilog is configured.

Comment: You can re-configure serilog either in `Main` or in the `.UseSerilog(...)` Action, as per the docs (https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting). Unless there's some other part to this question that you haven't told us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear and you not answering our questions in the comments is not helping, so guessing what you want, this is something you can do:

```cs
public static class Hosting
{
    public static bool _property1;
    public static string _property2;
    public static IHostBuilder UseMyService(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.ConfigureServices((context, _) =>
        {
            _property1 = context.Configuration["Property1"].ToLower() == "true";
            _property2 = context.Configuration["Property2"];
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can access the configuration through the `HostBuilderContext` which can be accessed though some of the extensions in `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`.

Note, the whole `ConfigureAppConfiguration` part you show in your code is not needed: [`CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.host.createdefaultbuilder) already does all those things for you (and more). Quote

> The following defaults are applied to the returned HostBuilder:
>
> - set the ContentRootPath to the result of GetCurrentDirectory()
> - load host IConfiguration from "DOTNET_" prefixed environment variables
> - load app IConfiguration from 'appsettings.json' and 'appsettings.[EnvironmentName].json'
> - load app IConfiguration from User Secrets when EnvironmentName is 'Development' using the entry assembly
> - load app IConfiguration from environment variables
> - configure the ILoggerFactory to log to the console, debug, and event source output
> - enables scope validation on the dependency injection container when EnvironmentName is 'Development'

(Edit, you could also use the `ConfigurationBinder` Methods like `GetValue<bool>` etc.)

Comment: Not sure how that helps, since the details are hiding in `.UseSerilog()`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman true. But this was just not a good question. Even with edits and scarce answers to our questions in the comments it is still not fully clear what the OP wants. I rewrote it.